# How to display div below of absolute or fixed div?

Tags: html, css

I have one div which is absolute or fixed and second div is normal. I have to display content below of absolute or fixed div. Below code, Normal div is displaying the content backside of absolute div.

Is it possible to force the content below of absolute div?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*
.A-absolute {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 40px 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}*/
 .A-absolute
  {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: top;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
color: #fff !important;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="A-absolute">
</div>

<div class="B">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consectetur Adipisicing Elit Adipisicing . Ab Saepe Aperiam, Illum Sint. Nisi, Eligendi Reruat Officiis Consectetur Assunda Commodi
  </p>
</div>



<div class="c">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consectetur Adipisicing Elit Adipisicing . Ab Saepe Aperiam, Illum Sint. Nisi, Eligendi Reruat Officiis Consectetur Assunda Commodi
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add the normal div inside the absolute div container, in that way you can achieve the above design

Comment: Thanks for replying. I edited my code. I want to understand that why we are adding padding. In case my absolute div padding is more than 150px the I have to set normal div more than 300px

Answer (score 2):

Cleanest way is to calculate the height of .A-absolute and give .B that much top padding:

```
.B {
    padding-top: 80px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mqajyyrv/1/

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.symlink, Incase .A-absolute{  padding: 100px 0;} then i have to set .B {padding-top: 160px;} then it is displyaing the second div. I want to force the second div.

Comment: Setting padding: 100px 0; means padding-top and padding-bottom are 100px in height, so you want to give .B 200px of padding-top.

Comment: Cool. Don't hesitate to click the check mark by my answer if it worked for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since the absolutely positioned element is 80px tall, give it a `top` value of `0` so it will stay at the top of the window, and apply top padding of `80px` to body. You could also use `margin-top: 80px` on `.B`

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 80px 0 0;
  }
  .A-absolute {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 40px 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="A-absolute">
  </div>

  <div class="B">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consectetur Adipisicing Elit Adipisicing . Ab Saepe Aperiam, Illum Sint. Nisi, Eligendi Reruat Officiis Consectetur Assunda Commodi</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Michael coker, I want to understand that why you added padding to body tag and Incase of absolute div I added an image then how to display content below?

Comment: @NarendraVerma I added padding to body to push the contents of all normally positioned elements down 80px to make room for the absolutely positioned element. Since you added `height: 350px` to the absolutely positioned element, you would apply `padding-top: 350px` to `body`, the absolutely positioned element will sit within that padding, and the rest of the content will be displayed below.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div A as a wrapper which is fixed or absolute and put B and C inside:

```
<body>
<div class="A-absolute-Wrapper">
   <div class="B"></div>
   <div class="C"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since absolute positioned elements goes out of the normal flow of elements so you must have to give padding equal to the height of the absolute element to the parent of the elements or margin equal to the height of absolute element to the element that you want below the absolute positioned div.